# Show results from different parcel tracking websites: issue with same origin policy

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like to have results from different parcel tracking websites (like https://www.17track.net and https://parcelsapp.com/) in a unique web page where I will input only a tracking number that will be parsed from different tracking websites... Since I cannot use API from parcel tracking websites cause those are quite expensive, I was thinking to embed in a webpage different iframes, one for each parcel tracking site but almost all those sites implement a same origin policy so the iframe won't work... do you have any ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this result? Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: This probably has to be done server-side with a web scraper which can then display onto your page. What backend are you using?

Comment: You may be able to make this work in the short term but not in the long term. The sites are selling access to their API and so are invested in preventing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you guys, well I wanted actually to do that client side, via HTML and JavaScript without touching the back end, but I see that it's quite tricky to do since tracking sites owners are actually the first ones that want to prevent it...